# How To Access Form Posted Values In ServiceStack Request Handler

Tags: servicestack

A payment provider is form posting values to a ServiceStack URL in our site.

The normal implementation pattern of our ServiceStack operations is to create a request DTO, give it some properties and specify a [Route("/blah/blah","POST")] attribute on the request DTO, create and Get or Post method in a Service specifying the request DTO as the only method argument.

This pattern works, but I discovered that the fields being posted to us vary, and so I now need to access the form posted values as a name-value collection.

How do I do that and what are the potential alternatives?

Just guessing, but my request DTO could inherit from some ServiceStack base class that exposes the name-value collection. Maybe use an interceptor to extract the name-values and inject them into my request DTO.

Looking for hard examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Service` class, which your service handler inherits from provides access to the `Request` object in the `base` class. This allows you to access `FormData` which is a `INameValueCollection` essentially the name/values you are looking for.

So given your `PaymentService` which inherits from `ServiceStack.Service`. In your handler method (such as `Post(PaymentRequest request)`) you can access the name/value collection using `base.Request.FormData["keyname"]`:

```cs
public class PaymentService : Service
{
    public void Post(PaymentRequest request)
    {
        // To access using the request DTO
        var amount = request.Amount;

        // To access the form values directly (from name/value collection)
        var tax = base.Request.FormData ["tax"];

        // To access the query string value of currency `?currency=USD`
        var currency = base.Request.QueryString ["currency"];

        // To access a value that may be form data, query string, cookie
        var item = base.Request.GetParam("item");
    }
}
```

If the request sends query string parameters you can also access them similarly using `base.Request.QueryString["keyname"]`.

If you want to find a value by keyname, but you don't know if the value is in the `QueryString`, `FormData`, `Cookies` or `Items` collection you can use the `base.Request.GetParam("keyname");` method. *Evaluated in the order given, left to right*

See [Access HTTP specific features in services](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Access-HTTP-specific-features-in-services) documentation for further information.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Hey Scott. Thanks. The only other thing I had to handle was the value of FormData["blah"] was a string array not a string as I had expected.